# Shell command for counting words in files

Tags: linux, shell

I want to run a command, that will count the number of words in all file. (From the selected number of files)

If i do like, `find ABG-Development/ -name "*.php" | grep "<?" | wc -l` , it will search only in the filename not the file contents.

And I tried one more way like

`find ABG-Development/ -name "*.php" -exec grep "<?" {} \; | wc -l`, I got error.

In above example I need how many time "

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)

```
find ABG-Development/ -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "<?" | wc -l
```